# Retrieving irq number of a NIC

Tags: c, linux

I need to retrieve an interrupt number of interface by its' name as appears in ifconfig.

Is there some standard API to do it?

Answer (score 3):

The interrupt number lives in sysfs. Look for the file `/sys/class/net/[ethname]/device/irq`. For example:

```
more /sys/class/net/*/device/irq
::::::::::::::
/sys/class/net/eth0/device/irq
::::::::::::::
30
::::::::::::::
/sys/class/net/eth1/device/irq
::::::::::::::
29
```

Answer (score 2):

`/sys/class/net/[ethname]/device/irq` should *legacy irq number*, device may not be using legacy irq, it may be using *msix*.

check

```
$ ls /sys/class/net/eth0/device/msi_irqs/
```

or

```
$ grep eth0 /proc/interrupts
```

Comment: Why are you answering a 4 year old question with information relevant to one hardware vendor? Additionally with predictable network interface names (circa `systemd v197`), `eth0` is no longer a guaranteed interface. Adding answers to old questions is probably not the best use of your time.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin How is that relevant to only one hardware vendor?